# What is rewind(stdin) for and why does C need it?

Tags: c

From my understanding, I need to write rewind(stdin) after inputting integers if I want to input char or string. Why do I need to do this and why can't C let me input a char after inputting int

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include<math.h>


void main()
{
    char c;
    
    int x, y,square;
    double root;

    


    do {
        printf("Enter integers = ");
        scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);

        square = pow(x, y);

        root = double(sqrt(square));

        printf("Squared = %d\n", square);
        printf("Square root = %.2lf\n", root);
        rewind(stdin); // If this isnt here it goes straight into the beginning instead of letting me input a char.
        
        printf("Continue ? (Y/N)");
        scanf("%c", &c);
        



    } while (c != 'N' );




}
```

Comment: The real problem is that `scanf("%c", &c)` will read the newline left behind by the previous `"%d"`. Replace `"%c"` with `" %c"` to skip over that newline (and any other whitespace). Whatever `rewind(stdin)` may be doing with your compiler and platform is unreliable and not portable.

Comment: I see. I tried using  " %c" and the result was the same as typing rewind(stdin).

Comment: There are tons of documentations (and uncounted posts here at SO) about `scanf()`. Please read some of them, at least the official one in the standard, and experiment to get a grip. It is a quite limited function, I would say just for convenience with low reqiurements, so a dedicated implementation for your needs would start with `fgets()` and some string functions, and if you want `sscanf()`. You might even try `"%1s"`, but make sure that the variable has room for the `'\0'`.

Comment: Also note `rewind(stdin)` only works when `stdin` is *seekable*, i.e. when a file is being redirected on `stdin`, e.g. `./yourprogram < somefile`

Comment: @david: `rewind` only rewinds seekable streams, but OP doesn't actually want to rewind the stream. So they don't want it to "work" in the normal sense of the word. It will "work" for their particular use case on a system where `rewind` empties the stream's internal buffer before attempting the `seek()`, which is legal behaviour but cannot be relied upon, and is what they are actually seeking to do.

Comment: @rici, yes, thank you. I understood, but since he had used that cockamamie method to avoid the whitespace, I was hoping to encourage him further with a comment to look into the use of `rewind()` on `stdin` a bit further and understand its limitations -- and why what he was doing was not the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments already pointed out, there's a remain new-line character at scanf("%c", &c).

What I want to mention why rewind(stdin) make your code works is that rewind(stdin) moves input buffer position and, for some streams, it truncates its internal buffer. That's why your code works correctly with rewind(stdin) since it empties remaining characters in the buffer.

You can have the same effect with the following code which also moves its its input buffer position.

```
printf("Enter integers = ");
scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

but, I found the following code has no effect with undefined behavior on Windows.

```
printf("Enter integers = ");
scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
fflush(stdin)
```